# Forcing a carriage return in textarea

Tags: html, textarea

I would like to start a textarea with inside a text that starts some line under the first line. Doing something like:

```
var myText = '\r \r \r HELLO';
```

doesn't work: HELLO is written on the first line, while

```
var myText = 'HELLO \r \r \r HELLO2';
```

puts correctly HELLO2 after HELLO. This means that `\r` is correct, but it doesn't work at the beginning of the textarea.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I had this problem once.. try \n

Comment: you should try to accept the answers to your previous questions

Comment: I'm not getting any issue with `\r` at http://jsfiddle.net/RwNPX/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to put space or `&nbsp;` before the "\r"?

Comment: This did the job. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16):

Try inserting `&#13;` into the text area.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use \r, use \n

Example:
`var myText = '\n \n \n HELLO';`

Answer (score 2):

In PHP I had to make sure to use double quotes instead of single.

```
$var1 = 'Test1 above /n/n Test below'; //will not work
$var2 = "Test2 above /n/n Test below"; //will work
echo = "<textarea>$var1</textarea><br /><textarea>$var2</textarea>";
```

Answer (score 0):

"\r" is to return to the begining of the line the, i forgot its name, i think is the cursor. But what you need is "\n" for a new line

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net.

Then do

`Var myText = "Hello" + Enviroment.NewLine + "Hello2";`

However if your using something else, i.e. Java, web languages then I advise you try `/n` followed by `/r`. I have had to use `"/n/r"` to get the result I wanted, after the `/r` was being ignored.

Comment: The question is how to get it _without_ the first "hello," and the code examples are almost certainly JavaScript (they're not valid C# or VB)

Comment: There was no tags on the original question, no reference to a language, and var is valid in C#. Campbell has since edited to the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

What browser and/or OS are you using?  [In my quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/Np2Bf/), both `\r` and `\n` yield the same (correct) result on Windows in IE 8, Firefox 3.6, and Chrome 9.

```
<textarea rows="5" id="r"></textarea>
<textarea rows="5" id="n"></textarea>
```

```
$(function() {
    $('#r').val('\r\r\rHello');
    $('#n').val('\n\n\nHello');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,
I soved this problem by adding 
 instead of \r\n. I suggest to check css attributes of textarea.

Please take note I won't return to see if there are question about mine text.

Comment: well as you see the text have a new line where i put what I'am adding in stead off: its an htlm tag for an new line br between <>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).